# How to use tflearn model to perform blob image processing in python

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection, tflearn

I want to find blob in a frame (or image), and apply the trained DNN to classify the regions.
However, I am using tflearn, and I don't know how to use the model trained using tflearn.

```
.
.
.
model.load('model.tflearn')
image_test = cv2.imread("test_fish.jpg", 0)
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image_test, 1.0, (300, 300), [128, 128, 128], False, False)
# I want to do something like model.setInput(blob)
.
.
.
```

Also, if anyone have time, I would like to seek for some advice on how to do self-learning in coding?

There are a lot of resources online but I just cannot develop my own program or solve difficult questions without tutorials. Am I too relying on existing codes? How can I improve and become a solid programmer?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you need not write the whole code from scratch but you can start with some use-case and getting piece of codes as required and stitching them accordingly to fit the solution. This way you will get to know how and where to use specific functions/piece of code. Also you can get ready code and try changing different things as per the result you require and you will end up having your own different version of code.
Please refer to code below for your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

rows = open("synset_words.txt").read().strip().split("\n")
classes = [r[r.find(" ") + 1:].split(",")[0] for r in rows]

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("bvlc_googlenet.prototxt","bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel")
#Here if you want to import a tensorflow model you can do it as below
#cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'graph.pbtxt')

image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
resized = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(resized, 1, (224, 224), (104, 117, 123))
print("First Blob: {}".format(blob.shape))

net.setInput(blob)
preds = net.forward()

idx = np.argsort(preds[0])[::-1][0]
text = "Label: {}, {:.2f}%".format(classes[idx],preds[0][idx] * 100)
cv2.putText(image, text, (5, 25),  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```